# Convergence of series ${\sum_{n >= 1} \sqrt{n}\ln(\cosh(1/n))}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The series is $${\sum_{n >= 1} \sqrt{n}\ln(\cosh(1/n))}$$

I´ve tried with the quotient criterion and with the limit criterion but the critiria does not decide. I know that this series converges but I can´t find an upper bound for the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that when $n\to +\infty,$

$$\ln (\cosh (\frac 1n))=\ln (1+\cosh (\frac 1n)-1) $$
$$\sim \cosh (\frac 1n)-1$$
$$= 2\sinh^2 (\frac {1}{2n})\sim \frac {2}{4n^2}\sim \frac {1}{2n^2}$$

thus
$$u_n=\sqrt {n}\ln (\cosh (\frac 1n))\sim \frac {1}{2n^{\frac 32}} $$

and $\sum u_n $ converges.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the first aproximation?

Comment: @AgustinCaputo $$\ln (1+X)\sim X $$ near $X=0$

Comment: Thankis you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{cosh}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}1+\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\ln\left(\text{cosh}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
You finally have the following asymptotic behaviour

> $$
> \sqrt{n}\ln\left(\text{cosh}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

What do you know about $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ ?

Comment: Is for a Calculus I course and we can´t use Laurent series :(

Comment: It's not a Laurent series

Comment: (+1) In my opinion, you should explicitly use equivalents from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\geq 0$ we have $\log\cosh x\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$, hence your series is convergent and bounded by $\frac{1}{2}\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$.
Actually
$$ \log\cosh\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{4}{\pi^2 n^2 (2m+1)^2}\right)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{h+1} 4^h}{h \pi^{2h}n^{2h}(2m+1)^{2h}} $$
$$ \log\cosh\frac{1}{n} =\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{h+1}(4^h-1)\zeta(2h)}{h\pi^{2h} n^{2h}}$$

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\sqrt{n}\log\cosh\frac{1}{n} =\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{h+1}(4^h-1)\zeta(2h)\zeta(2h-1/2)}{h\pi^{2h}}$$
hence the original series can be bounded by $\frac{1}{2}\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{12}\zeta\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{45}\zeta\left(\frac{11}{2}\right)\leq\color{red}{\sqrt{5}-1}.$